# How to change proxy settings programmatically?

Tags: web-access, system, configuration, networking

I'm using version 10.2 on Linux, and need to access some web services via proxy server sometimes. Is there a way to change the proxy settings, which can be modified manually in the "Preferences" AFAIK, programmatically because the settings may vary in different contexts? I looked into `SystemOptions[]` etc but didn't find anything related.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One can read the current setting using the undocumented symbol `$InternetProxyRules`.

The undocumented functions to change the proxy settings are in the `` PacletManager` `` context.

The "Use proxy settings from my system or browser" setting is equivalent to

```
PacletManager`UseInternetProxy[Automatic]
```

the "Direct connection to the Internet" setting is equivalent to

```
PacletManager`UseInternetProxy[False]
```

and the "Use the following settings:" setting is equivalent to

```
PacletManager`UseInternetProxy[True]
```

Proxy settings can be set with `` PacletManager`SetInternetProxy ``. For example

```
PacletManager`SetInternetProxy["HTTP", {"proxystring", 1}]
```

would set the HTTP Proxy to *proxystring* and its corresponding port to *1*.